# junit spring boot ScheduledExecutorService schedule does not run

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, junit

`ScheduledExecutorService` is used in a bean constructor, which should run when spring boot starts.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public TestController() {
        service.schedule(() -> {
            // task
        }, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        service.shutdown();
    }
```

However, sometimes, the task is never called. And in debug mode, `service.shutdown()` gives service as:

```
active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0
```

While this does not happen all the time. When it runs as I think it should, service object at the same line gives either queued tasks or completed tasks 1.
This only happens during junit test,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ScheduledExecutorServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

[image: debug mode shows service has 0 queued or completed tasks]

Answer (score 0):

You may delay the controller thread to wait for the execution of the scheduled thread with a call to

```
scheduledFuture.get() or 
scheduledFuture.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit),
```

where

```
scheduledFuture = service.schedule(..)
```

before

```
service.shutdown().
```

You are scheduling the task to run in another thread but shutting down the scheduler service immediately. shutdown method initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted and it does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. It may happen that sometimes your scheduler service is already shut down before getting the task, hence it shows queued or completed task as 0.

Comment: I don't think shutdown causes the problem. Because the breakpoint is set before it.